# Which echart diagram can be used for something like a process flow diagram?

Tags: javascript, charts, dataflow-diagram, echarts

I am trying to implement a flow diagram using echarts library by Baidu. I thought the closest match for it, would be the tree diagram. Here's an example: [Tree](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/example/tree.html#-en)
Kindly suggest some other diagram which would portray a flow diagram better.
[image]

The diagram I'm trying to implement is as shown in the picture above!

Comment: ECharts doesn't support this type of diagram yet, and neither is it in recent plan. You may need to make an extension to do so. But it may be easier for those who are not familiar with ECharts to draw the diagram with Canvas itself.

Comment: thank you @Ovilia I am currently looking into how mermaid js library might suit my requirement